# Print clearly from web browser to EPSON U220 printer

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dot-matrix

I do have an HTML receipt (basic only text) from EPSON U220 printer. The printing function works with window.print(). But the print i get is not clear. I found that as because web print it as an image, it get bury. I use Chrome.

What is the best possible option with using Chrome and EPSON U220,  to print clear text receipt?

Comment: You might need to use a browser or an app

Comment: @rgedit yes I use Chrome

Comment: You need to send raw text and commands to the printer. Modern drivers send an image like you said and the resolution of the printer is just too low for proper printing. Use a lib like [python-escpos](https://github.com/python-escpos/python-escpos) to get the best of it. Or send your text and formatting commands with `lpr`.